# Only Allow Schema Change from Backendless Console

Tags: backendless

I want to restrict creating or modifying the data model schema for backendless. Specifically, only want to create or modify the data model schema using the console.  The data model schema should not be modified using the API.

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It this point it can be achieved by you making sure that your code stays consistent and does not introduce new fields/properties. Adding a new field to a class and then saving an instance of the class with the API will result in a new column being created. So to avoid that make sure that your classes at any point of time represent the schema of the backend.